# How to match specific position based on offset number with a specific number of length with regex?

Tags: regex

I need to match characters without knowing what characters they will be and the only data I have is an offset number telling me where to start the match and a length number telling me how long the match has to be.

For example:

My string is: "Susan go to the store everyday"

"offset":17
"length":5

Would match "store"

^.{5} This regex matches the length, but is there a way to add an offset rule to this?

My tool doesn't support capture groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your regex tool/language support it, you could use a capture group here:

```regex
^.{17}(.{5})
```

### Demo

This would skip the first 17 characters, and then capture the following 5 characters in the first capture group.

**Edit:**

If your regex tool *doesn't* have capture groups, you could also use a fixed width lookbehind, e.g.

```regex
(?<=^.{17}).{5}
```

### Demo

Comment: My tool doesn't support capture groups :/

Comment: @DavidToledo Then use a fixed width lookbehind.  If your tool also doesn't support that...then you need a more powerful tool unfortunately.